# g++: -O1 -fdevirtualize -flto leading to problems on ifstream::widen

Tags: optimization, g++, vtable

If I place the following code in test.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::ifstream a;
    do{
        a.widen('\n');
    }while(true);
}
```

and invoke g++ with

```
g++ -O1 -fdevirtualize -flto -m64 -o out Tergiversative.cpp
```

on g++ version 5.1.0, then the produced executable crashes on the first call to `a.widen`. This doesn't happen if I wrap it in (for instance)

```
do{
    a.widen('\n');
}while(false);
```

because it's just "flattened", but it does occur in any other loop, like

```
int i=2;
do{
    a.widen('\n');
    i--;
}while(i>0);
```

Specifically, inside of `ctype<char>`'s `widen`, it gets to (from `locale_facets.h`)

```
widen(char __c) const{
  if (_M_widen_ok)
    return _M_widen[static_cast<unsigned char>(__c)];
  this->_M_widen_init();
  return this->do_widen(__c);
}
```

it makes the virtual call to `do_widen`. When any of the above three flags are disabled, this works fine; when all three are enabled, then the vtable isn't populated correctly somehow, and the do_widen pointer is left NULL, giving a SIGSEGV at runtime. When it's not placed in a loop (or a trivial loop, like the do/while(false) ) then g++ transforms the above into a call to `std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>>::widen('\n')`, and nothing bad happens.

Is there something wrong with my code that is invoking undefined behavior? Or is this a weird edge-case in some optimization that I'm triggering? I've only gotten it to occur when building 64-bit executable (`-m32` makes it run fine), and only with all of `-O1 -fdevirtualize -flto`. I checked each of the subflags turned by `-O1`, and they don't trigger it, so it must one of the "invisible" optimizations that checks the `-On` level directly. The `-fdevirtualize` being relevant would make sense given that it's a virtual call that's failing -- ***but*** the call hasn't been devirtualized. The vtable is just unpopulated.

Any help understanding this would be appreciated!